# jQuery.fn.extend, has no method with MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I want to register a function in my view using jQuery.fn.extend. So I defined it in the _Layoyt.cshtml file in my Asp MVC3 application. following is the code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.extend({
            tagBox :function(options) { }
        }); 
</script>
```

In my view I use the following code to call the method

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
       $('.tags').tagBox({ maxTagCount: 5, initialTags: [] });
   });
```

but when I check the page with chrome I see an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagBox'
>   d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWithjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
>   d.extend.readyjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19 c.addEventListener.A

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused what `$.fn.extend` or simply `$.extend` are used for. These are for overriding values of one object to another and ensuring that there is a value defined for that property. What I think you are looking for is a jquery plugin. This is a shell of one.

```
(function($){

    var _defaults = {
        your:"defaults",
        you:"Want to extend"
    };

    $.fn.tagBox = function(options){

        var _opts = $.extend({}, _defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){

        });
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

[This article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) taught me a lot of the basics when I first started learning how to write them and I often go back for the example as a base.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried this before I use $.fn.extend and the result was the same. That is why I changed my code to use $.fn.extend. I will read the article you provided and try again.

Comment: I tried this again still the error is there. I tried some different versions of jQuery too but still can not call the function correnctly.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to locrizak's excellent answer, if your code is still not working, in what order do these scripts appear in the rendered HTML?

If the `$.fn.extend(` is declared before the jquery lib is loaded, it will not work. Also, if you execute `$('.tags').tagBox({ maxTagCount: 5, initialTags: [] });` in your view before the function extension is declared, it will not work. The scripts must be ordered like so:

1. Load jQuery library
2. Declare your function extension
3. Use / invoke the function extension

If this doesn't help, try posting the HTML rendered to the browser, so that we can inspect and help you figure out what's going wrong.